DraggableScrollableSheet with tabviews rendering issues
Im trying to create a draggable bottom sheet containing tab bars and tab views. While the sheet header tab bar buttons are being shown correctly, the tabviews are being shown with render issue(long red error)
I have no idea where exactly Im going wrong. I would be really glad if someone could help me in it.
DraggableScrollableSheet(
  initialChildSize: 0.14,
  minChildSize: 0.14,
  snap: true,
  maxChildSize: 1.0, // Adjust the max height as needed
  builder: (BuildContext context, ScrollController scrollController) {
    return Container(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(16.0),
          topRight: Radius.circular(16.0),
        ),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.black26,
            blurRadius: 10.0,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      child: CustomScrollView(
        controller: scrollController,
        slivers:  [
          const SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  width: 50,
                  child: Divider(thickness: 4, color: Colors.black12),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, right: 15, top: 10),
                  child: SizedBox(width: double.infinity, child: Text("What's On, Dundee", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),

          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: DefaultTabController(
                length: 2,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    const Material(
                      child: TabBar(
                       labelColor: Colors.black,
                       indicatorColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
                       tabs: [
                         Tab(text: "Events"),
                         Tab(text: "Discounts"),
                       ],
                      ),
                    ),


                    SliverFillRemaining(// ERROR POINTING HERE
                      child: TabBarView(
                        children: [
                          buildEventList(context, "Events"),
                          buildEventList(context, "Discounts"),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )

                  ],
                )
            ),
          )
        ],
      )
    );
  },
),

Widget buildEventList(BuildContext context, String eventType) {
  List<Venue> venues = eventType == "Events"
      ? Provider.of<VenueProvider>(context).getTodaysEvents()
      : Provider.of<VenueProvider>(context).getUpcomingEvents();

  if (venues.isEmpty) {
    return SliverToBoxAdapter(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 200,
            child: OverflowBox(
              minHeight: 200, maxHeight: 200, child: lot.Lottie.asset('assets/animations/EmptyAd.json'),
            ),
          ),
          const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
            child: Text(
              "It looks quiet tonight\nCheck back later to see What's on",
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16, // Adjust font size as needed
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  return SliverList(
    delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((BuildContext context, int index) {
      Venue venue = venues[index];
      return Column(
        children: venue.advertisements.map((ad) {
          return buildAdvertisementCard(context, venue, ad);
        }).toList(),
      );
    },
    ),
  );

}

error:
The following assertion was thrown building SliverFillRemaining(child: TabBarView, mode: [scrollable]):
A RenderFlex expected a child of type RenderBox but received a child of type RenderSliverFillRemainingWithScrollable.

RenderObjects expect specific types of children because they coordinate with their children during layout and paint. For example, a RenderSliver cannot be the child of a RenderBox because a RenderSliver does not understand the RenderBox layout protocol.
The RenderFlex that expected a RenderBox child was created by: Column ← _TabControllerScope ← DefaultTabController ← SliverToBoxAdapter ← Viewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#64b2e] ← Semantics ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#24366] ← Listener ← _ScrollableScope ← ⋯
The RenderSliverFillRemainingWithScrollable that did not match the expected child type was created by: _SliverFillRemainingWithScrollable ← SliverFillRemaining ← Column ← _TabControllerScope ← DefaultTabController ← SliverToBoxAdapter ← Viewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#64b2e] ← Semantics ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#24366] ← ⋯
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  SliverFillRemaining SliverFillRemaining

I tried using expanded, flexible for the tab views but there was no progress and still caused the rendering issues.
